# Magento Reorder and Resize Price Excl Incl Tax Labels

Tags: css, magento

Does anyone know how to reorder the excluding and including tax labels on `Magento 2`?

An example of how I want to reorder them in the image below:
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grULi.png)

Also, my `incl tax price size` is slightly smaller than the `excl tax price`. This only appears to be an issue on the product page, is it possible to change this by `CSS`?

I have the following CSS which I use to display the `incl tax` label:

```html
.price-excluding-tax::before {
    content: attr(data-label) ": ";
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
.price-including-tax::before {
    content: attr(data-label) ": ";
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
.price-container .price-including-tax + .price-excluding-tax, .price-container .weee, .price-container .price-including-tax + .price-excluding-tax .price, .price-container .weee .price, .price-container .weee + .price-excluding-tax::before, .price-container .weee + .price-excluding-tax .price {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

Comment: I have tried changing font-size: 1.4rem; on all 3 occurances to be the same too which doesnt fix the difference in price

Comment: Managed to fix the price size with .product-info-price .price-box .price {
    font-size: 1.4rem;

Just need to find out how to reorder the labels